# Fedora30 upgrade: Cannot run KDE as normal user

Tags: fedora, xorg, d-bus, kde5

I've upgraded from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30.
Alghough root can use KDE normally, I fail to use it as a normal user, so it seems permission related. An almost black fullscreen window appears with a responsive mouse arrow in the middle of the screen. 
Some data that may be relevant:

I am seeing problems with `/lib64/libQt5DBus.so.5`, even after reinstalling it.

I don't see any error in the normal user Xorg.0.log file, I can post it if needed.

I have also seen some errors related to kglobalaccel, but removing the .local, .config and .kde folders did not help either. But `journalctl` says (not sure what to do with this):

```
systemd[1133]: Started dbus-:1.2-org.kde.kglobalaccel@0.service.
kglobalaccel5[1531]: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
audit[1531]: ANOM_ABEND auid=500 uid=500 gid=500 ses=2 pid=1531 comm="kglobalaccel5" exe="/usr/bin/kglobalaccel5" sig=6 res=1
kglobalaccel5[1531]: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
kglobalaccel5[1531]: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
                     Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcoredump.slice.
audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-coredump@0-1537-0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 1537/UID 0).
dbus-broker-launch[1483]: Activation request for 'org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.KTp.Approver' failed.
dbus-broker-launch[1483]: Activation request for 'org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.KTp.KdedIntegrationModule' failed.
systemd[1133]: dbus-:1.2-org.kde.kglobalaccel@0.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
systemd[1133]: dbus-:1.2-org.kde.kglobalaccel@0.service: Succeeded.
systemd-coredump[1541]: Process 1531 (kglobalaccel5) of user 500 dumped core.

                                            Stack trace of thread 1531:
                                            #0  0x00007fd273722e75 raise (libc.so.6)
                                            #1  0x00007fd27370d895 abort (libc.so.6)
                                            #2  0x00007fd273b33af5 _ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                            #3  0x00007fd2740dc29f _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate25createPlatformIntegrationEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                                            #4  0x00007fd2740dcaf8 _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate21createEventDispatcherEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                                            #5  0x00007fd273d16975 _ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate4initEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                                            #6  0x00007fd2740de253 _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate4initEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                                            #7  0x00007fd2740df198 _ZN15QGuiApplicationC2ERiPPci (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                                            #8  0x0000555c57159481 n/a (kglobalaccel5)
                                            #9  0x00007fd27370ef33 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                                            #10 0x0000555c571597de n/a (kglobalaccel5)
```

Look at some console output:

```
Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86MonBrightnessCycle
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86RotationLockToggle
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
startkde: Starting up...
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid environment assignments
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface:serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Cannot find �rg.kde.KSplash.setStage' in object /KSplash at org.kde.KSplash
kf5.kded: found kded module "colord" by prepending 'kded_' to the library path, please fix your metadata.
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL 
colord: "/home/gato/.local/share/icc/.." is not an ICC profile
colord: "/home/gato/.local/share/icc/." is not an ICC profile
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
kdeinit5: Fatal IO error: client killed 
kdeinit5: sending SIGHUP to children.
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
kdeinit5: sending SIGTERM to children.
kdeinit5: Exit.
Unexpected response from KInit (response = 0).
startkde: Could not start ksmserver. Check your installation.
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
xinit: connection to X server lost
GOT SIGHUP
Antares:~> startkde: Shutting down...
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/500/kdeinit5__0) failed: : No such file or directory
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
startkde: Done.

Couldn't start kglobalaccel from org.kde.kglobalaccel.service: QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply", "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.")
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
```

Comment: BTW, I can run KDE as a second normal user. I tried moving the ~/.kde* ~/.config and ~/.cache stuff without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the new xinit is incompatible with my old .xinitrc file. I added the content of .xinitrc to .profile and everything worked again.